microsoft sql server management studio ошибка
Здравствуйте, вы случаем не знаете как исправить данную ошибку? И такая ошибка происходит при заполнении любой таблицы которой есть у меня в базе данных.
Исходный код с помощью которого создавал таблицы:
CREATE DATABASE Personal24
GO
USE Personal24
GO
CREATE TABLE Department(
id_dep tinyint identity PRIMARY KEY,
name_dep varchar(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE Post(
id_post tinyint IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Name_post varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Post_money decimal (7,2) NOT NULL,
Days tinyint NOT NULL,
Count_post tinyint NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE Persona(
id_man smallint IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
PassNo varchar(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Surname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
Name1 varchar(12) NOT NULL,
Birthdate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
Sex char(1) NOT NULL,
Education varchar(15),
Married bit,
Children tinyint
) 
GO
CREATE TABLE Worker(
id_work smallint IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
id_man smallint REFERENCES Persona not null,
id_post tinyint REFERENCES Post,
id_dep tinyint REFERENCES Department,
main_work bit NOT NULL,
stavka decimal (4,2) NOT NULL,
date_work datetime,
UNIQUE(id_man, main_work)
)
GO


INSERT INTO Department (name_dep) VALUES ('Что то') - При условии что у вас id с автоинкрементом

Добро пожаловать на ru.SO!!! =>...Постарайтесь сами локализовать проблему, выделить минимальный фрагмент кода, на котором, как вы считаете возникает проблема. Прочитайте о том, как создать минимальный, но самодостаточный пример, демонстрирующий проблему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
документация как делать запрос https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp на Insert ваши скобки почему то каждая отдельно оборачивает значение

@SwaD
с изменениями которые вы написали остаётся всё та же ошибка
INSERT INTO Department (name_dep) VALUES  ('Адміністрація'),  ('Бухгалтерія'),  ('Технічний'); GO 
ошибка:
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Departme__311512841328F4C2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Department'. The duplicate key value is (Адміністрація).
The statement has been terminated.
(3 rows affected)

1: Переведите текст ошибки в любом доступном вам переводчике. 2: выполните select * from Department и вы там должны увидеть уже существующий ключ, на который ругается. Если переводчика нет, то ошибка говорит, что вы пытаетесь вставить значение, которое в поле уже есть. Ограничение по уникальности наложено вот этим name_dep varchar(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL
